# How to sort elements of List<EObject>?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, eclipse-emf

I want to sort `EObject` elements in List wrt to the name in ascending order.
I tried using the below code but I am getting compiler error.

I tried:

```
List<EObject> list = new ArrayList<EObject>();
list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: I can see no `name` in [EObject](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject.html).

Comment: Let’s assume that the list contains the names from a model class.

Answer (score 1):

EObject must be a comparable object to be sorted by java. In your object class definition you need to use implements Comparable. You then need to override the compareTo() method from the comparable interface with a set of arguments that sets the sorting precedent for the objects.

Comment: *"EObject must be a comparable object to be sorted by java"* That's wrong, you can sort arbitrary objects with a `Comparator`.

Comment: I see what you're saying but they're using the naturalOrder() sorting method. With no other code to go off of, to maintain that code structure they would need to implement the comparable interface within EObject, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`

Here's an example:

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1,o2)->o1.name.compareTo(o2.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of two ways.

- Implement the Comparable interface in your class.  This creates a natural ordering for your object.

```
public class EObject implements Comparable<EObject>{
     private String name;
       // perhaps other fields, constructors, and getters/setters
     public EObject(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(EObject ob) {
        // since you are comparing Strings, use String's compareTo method
        return name.compareTo(ob.name);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Some data

```
List<EObject>  list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new EObject("A"),
            new EObject("X"),
            new EObject("Y"),
            new EObject("H"),
            new EObject("F"),
            new EObject("B"),
            new EObject("G"),
            new EObject("R"),
            new EObject("S")));

list.sort(null); // null says use natural order
```

prints

```
[A, B, F, G, H, R, S, X, Y]
```

And this will reverse the natural order you implemented

```
list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[Y, X, S, R, H, G, F, B, A]
```

- If you have not implemented the Comparable interface you can do the above like this.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(EObject::getName));
// or for reversed order of names
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(EObject::getName).reversed());
```